# saving changes to a row in django

Tags: django

I have a table with a user as a foreign key.  I'm displaying the data in a template.

I'd like the user to be able to edit or delete the data.  I know that there's a save() method for doing this, but I don't understand how to access a particular row.  If I have the following model:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    needs_repairs = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s'%(self.item, self.needs_repairs)
```

And here's my form:

```
class InventoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = '__all__'
```

And a view:

```
def inventory(request):
    model = Inventory
    stuff = Inventory.objects.all()
    form = InventoryForm(data = request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.save()
            # return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = InventoryForm()
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('inventory.html', {
            'form':form, 'stuff':stuff
            }, RequestContext(request))
```

And my template that collects and displays data:

```html
<div>
 <div class="formfloatleft">

  <h2>Truck Inventory </h2>
  <div class="tablewrap">
   <table class="gradienttable"> 
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th><p>Whatcha got?</p></th>
      <th><p>Needs Repairs</p></th>
      <th><p>Change</p></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <div class="datatables">
      {% for things in stuff %}
       <tr class="datarow">
        <td>{{things.item}}</td>
        <td>{{things.needs_repairs}}</td>
       <td>
        <form method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="submit" value="edit or remove me">
              </form>
          </td>
       </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div class='formfloatright' >
  <h2>Add stuff</h2>
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <ul>
       {{ form.as_ul}}
   </ul>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
 </div>

</div>
```

I've tried setting up a function which was called when the user clicked the edit button.  This didn't work.

```
def delete_item(item_id):
    thing = Inventory.objects.get(pk=id)
    thing.item = None
    thing.save()
```

It didn't work, and then I wound up with circuitous errors.  I've deleted it, and can't replicate them (sorry).

How can I allow a user (who has permissions) to select and edit a row using the provided button? Let's say one of the items gets repaired or breaks, for example.  I've read the docs, and googled extensively, and I'm still confused about how this is done.

Thanks so much.

Comment: what error did you get ? My guess is the field .item cannot be None. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/

Answer (score 0):

This may be giving you Integrity error, I Think so error will be..

null value in column "item" violates not-null constraint

**Try this** -

```
def delete_item(item_id):
    thing = Inventory.objects.get(pk=id)
    thing.item = ''
    thing.save()
```

**OR**

```
Inventory.objects.filter(id=id).update(item='')
```

Hope this will work for you.